# Searching for questions tagged [or] returns ALL questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search, tag-search

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/or

It returns **all** questions :) Even a search on [`[or]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bor%5D) doesn't work, it get redirected to the very same URL. Maybe the search algorithm should count the search words before blindly applying the OR.

*This might be `[status-bydesign]`, but I was just doing a tag cleanup. I finished with [`[and]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/and) and wanted to check if there are any unnecessary `[or]` tags. It would be nice to make the search algo a bit smarter though.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not allowed to create a tag named "or" -- that string is specifically blacklisted from ever being a tag -- so this is irrelevant.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags

Comment: Ah, that's a Good Thing! Are there more tags in the blacklist?