# 'infavorites:[userid]' searches on some users with no marked favorites returns *all* posts

Tags: bug, search, bookmarks

I just stumbled across an apparent minor bug in the site search. In some cases, searching `infavorites:[userid]` on a user with no marked favorites returns what appears to be *every post* on that sub-site. For example, I get the following search hit counts, at last check:

- [aria](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/522/aria?tab=favorites) on Chem.SE — [46,464 results](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=infavorites%3A522)
- [Salman](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/24332/salman?tab=favorites) on Bio.SE — [34,173 results](https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=infavorites%3A24332)
- [Robert Reid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253960/robert-reid?tab=favorites) on SO — [35,567,067 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3A253960)
- [prusswan](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/46/prusswan?tab=favorites) on Chess.SE — [11,691 results](https://chess.stackexchange.com/search?q=infavorites%3A46)
- [RussAbbott](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/7163/russabbott?tab=favorites) on Physics.SE — [241,926 results](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=infavorites%3A7163)

Interestingly, this doesn't happen for all users with no favorites marked, e.g.:

- [SamSol](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/25085/samsol?tab=favorites) on Physics.SE — [0 results](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=infavorites%3A25085)

---

I imagine this is (loosely?) related to these:

- [Searching for invalid advanced searches returns everything](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217349/searching-for-invalid-advanced-searches-returns-everything)
- [Searching for questions tagged [or] returns ALL questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48553/searching-for-questions-tagged-or-returns-all-questions)
- [Searching for user:something returns every question and answer (13.3m results)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171610/searching-for-usersomething-returns-every-question-and-answer-13-3m-results)
- [Why does searching for `user:` return all questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208108/why-does-searching-for-user-return-all-questions)

The difference here is that `infavorites:[validuserid]` is a valid search, so it *should* return zero hits for favorites-free users, I'd think?